# Java - Elliptic Curve Field Element Arithmetic in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I have been under the impression that it is more proper to perform arithmetic operations on exponents using ECFieldElement objects instead of BigIntegers, but according to my tests, doing so yields incorrect results.

Test Routines (JUnit):

```
class ArithmeticTest
{

  @Test
  public void testMultDistributativity_BigInteger()
  {
      ECPoint g = getG();

      for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
      {
        BigInteger a, b, c;

        a = randomIntInField(false);
        b = randomIntInField(false);
        c = a.add(b);

        ECPoint gA = g.multiply(a);
        ECPoint gB = g.multiply(b);
        ECPoint gC = g.multiply(c);
        ECPoint sum = gA.add(gB);

        assertEquals(gC, sum);
      }
  }

  @Test
  public void testMultDistributativity_ECFieldElement_SmallValues()
  {
      assertTrue(checkMultDistributativity_ECFieldElement(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.TEN));
  }

  @Test
  public void testMultDistributativity_ECFieldElement_RandomValues()
  {
      BigInteger a, b;
      int failureCount=0;

      for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
      {
        a = randomIntInField(false);
        b = randomIntInField(false);

        if (!checkMultDistributativity_ECFieldElement(a, b))
            failureCount++;
      }

      assertTrue(failureCount==0, "Failed on " + Integer.toString(failureCount) + " out of 1000 runs.");
  }

  private boolean checkMultDistributativity_ECFieldElement(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
  {
      ECFieldElement fA, fB, fC;
      ECPoint gA, gB, gC, sum;

      fA = getFieldElement(a);
      fB = getFieldElement(b);
      fC = fA.add(fB);

      gA = getG().multiply(a);
      gB = getG().multiply(b);
      gC = getG().multiply(fC.toBigInteger());
      sum = gA.add(gB);

      return gC.equals(sum);
  }
```

`testMultDistributativity_BigInteger` and `testMultDistributativity_ECFieldElement_SmallValues` succeed, but `testMultDistributativity_ECFieldElement_RandomValues` fails on half of its test cases.

Incidentally, 1/2 is the probability of two random field elements adding up to a number larger than the field order. I don't understand how this can mess things up though.

Loading the curve:

```
  private java.security.spec.EllipticCurve curve;
  private org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve bcCurve;
  private ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec;
  private final BigInteger fieldOrder;
  private static final int FIELD_ELEMENT_BIT_SIZE = 256;

  static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
  }

  public ArithmeticTest()
  {
    spec= ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1");
    bcCurve = spec.getCurve();

    ECNamedCurveSpec conversionSpec = new ECNamedCurveSpec(spec.getName(), spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
    curve = conversionSpec.getCurve();

    fieldOrder = new BigInteger ("ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff", 16);
  }
```

And these are the helper functions:

```
  private ECPoint getG()
  {
    return spec.getG();
  }

  private ECFieldElement getFieldElement(BigInteger i)
  {
    return bcCurve.fromBigInteger(i);
  }

  private randomIntInField(boolean nonzero)
  {
    final int ARGUMENT_IS_LARGER = -1;
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger result;
    int watchDog = 1000;

    do {
        result = new BigInteger(FIELD_ELEMENT_BIT_SIZE, rand);

        if (--watchDog == 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Damn what are the odds?");
    }
    while ( nonzero && result.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || result.compareTo(fieldOrder)!= ARGUMENT_IS_LARGER);

    return result;

  }
}
```

Can the problem be from the randomization somehow?

Comment: Could you try and run the [`normalize`](http://javadox.com/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.53/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECPoint.html#normalize--) function on the `ECPoint` instances after you've performed the calculations and see if you get the correct results?

Comment: Interesting point, thanks!
Unfortunately though, it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Just tried this test, it passes:

    `public void equals_representationNoSeCuenta() {
        ECPoint p = getG().twice();
        ECPoint pNormalized = p.normalize();

        assertEquals(pNormalized, p);
    }`
(Sorry this is probably not the best way to post code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have been under the impression that it is more proper to perform
>   arithmetic operations on exponents using ECFieldElement objects
>   instead of BigIntegers, but according to my tests, doing so yields
>   incorrect results.

No! Exponents (the scalar arguments to ECPoint.multiply) are most definitely not to be handled using ECFieldElement. Scalars should be added to each other modulo the group order, which is available via ECCurve.getOrder.

Your test therefore fails any time the sum fC gets reduced against the field modulus (~50% as you say).

Comment: Oh my, this should have been obvious! Thanks.